# Simple php Calculation function dosent get called?

Tags: php, function

User submits a number (Temperatur in Fahrenheit)
My Code takes the user number ,converts to celsius and then outputs it.

unfortunately it dosent output :)

i did echo the user input - that works, but my output in celsius is displayed as 0

```
<?php 

$tempInCelsius = 0;
$temp = $_GET['temp'];

function tempcalc($a){
global $tempInCelsius;
    ($a - 32) * 5/9;
return $placeholder;
};

tempcalc($temp);


echo $placeholder;
print "<br>";
echo $temp;

?>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Your function makes little sense.  You first set access to a global variable (which you don't use), you do a calculation without assigning the result and return a variable which isn't set.

Comment: put calculation into `$placeholder` variable then do `echo tempcalc($temp);`

Comment: Why not simply `echo (($_GET['temp'] - 32) * 5/9); print '<br>'; echo $_GET['temp'];`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. i messed up my brain at the beginning but figured it out myself at the end.

```
 $temp = $_GET['temp'];

  
    function tempcalc($num1)
    {
        $out = round(($num1 - 32) * (5 / 9));
        echo $out;
}
```